# Simple query language for CSV files

Tags: java, csv, dsl

I'm struggling to improve this command-line java application, which reads CSV or txt files, ands allows the user do some "queries" with the data. I can't use any external library, so I'm doing it all and now I'm trying to do some refactoring on it, to let it be scalable, and maybe in the future I could add some new commands / queries. I tried some design patterns like builders, interfaces and etc ..., but it does not seem right.

Do you have any tip to abstract this in some elegant way? I will post the first working version of the application to you guys give it a look:

---

Reader.java - this class reads the file and returns an array with all the rows and each row another array in which it will store each attribute of the row:

```
public class Reader {

    public ReaderConfig readerConfig;   

    public Reader(ReaderConfig readerConfig){
        this.readerConfig = readerConfig;
    }

    public List<String[]> read() {
        List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readerConfig.getPath()));

            String row = "";
            while ((row = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] properties = row.split(readerConfig.getDelimiter());
                rows.add(properties);
            }

            br.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rows;
    }
}
```

---

ReaderConfig.java - It will parameterize Reader.java, based on user input:

```
public class ReaderConfig {

    private String path;
    private String delimiter;
    private boolean hasHeader;

    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void setPathFile() {
        System.out.println("Enter the full path of the file ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if(FileUtils.isFileExtensionValid(FileUtils.getFileExtension(input))){
            try {
                new FileReader(input);
                this.path = input;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid file path!!");
                setPathFile();
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid extension! Avaliable extension: .txt and .csv");
            setPathFile();
        }
    }

    public void setDelimiter() {
        System.out.println("Enter the delimiter used by file (Example ;)");
        String input = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        if(input.length() == 0){
            System.out.println("Invalid delimiter!");
            setDelimiter();
        }

        this.delimiter = input;
    }

    public void setHasHeader() {
        System.out.println("Does the file have header? (Y/N)");
        String input = scanner.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();

        if(InputUtils.isBooleanInputValid(input)){
            this.hasHeader = InputUtils.evalInputToBoolean(input);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid command!");
            setHasHeader();
        }

    }

    /** GETTERS */
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public String getDelimiter() {
        return delimiter;
    }

    public boolean hasHeader() {
        return hasHeader;
    }
}
```

And last but not least, the main class that will run the application:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        ReaderConfig readerConfig = new ReaderConfig();           
        Reader reader = new Reader(readerConfig);

        List<String[]> data = reader.read();
        System.out.println("File loaded...");

        //Header information 
        String[] headers = {};
        if(readerConfig.hasHeader()){
            headers = data.get(0);
            System.out.println("Avaliable headers: " + Arrays.toString(headers));
        }

        //Listen console for commands:
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

         while (true) {
             System.out.println("Enter a command (or QUIT to exit): ");
             String input = scanner.nextLine();

             if(input.toLowerCase().equals("quit")){
                 scanner.close();
                 System.out.println("Bye.");
                 break;

             } else if(input.equals("select *")){
                 System.out.println("Total records: " + data.size());

             } else if(input.matches("select distinct")){

                 int headerIndex = -1;               
                 if(headers.length > 0) {
                     headerIndex = Arrays.asList(headers).indexOf(getParameter("select distinct", input));
                 }else{
                     //If not have a header, check if the column index has been passed as parameter
                     String isNumberRegex = "\\d+";
                     String parameter = getParameter("count distinct \\[(.*?)\\]", input);
                     if(parameter.matches(isNumberRegex)){
                         headerIndex = new Integer(parameter);
                     }
                 }
                 if(headerIndex != -1){
                     Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                     for(String[] props : data){
                         set.add(props[headerIndex]);
                     }
                     System.out.println("Total records: " + set.size()); 
                 }else{
                     System.out.println("Header not found!");
                 }

             } else if(input.matches("filter") && headers.length > 0) {

                 int propIndex = Arrays.asList(headers).indexOf(getParameter("filter", input));
                 String value = getValue("filter", input);
                 System.out.println(headers[propIndex]);
                 int cont = 0;
                 for(String[] test : data){
                     if(Arrays.asList(test).contains(value)){
                         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
                         cont++;
                     }
                 }
                 System.out.println("Total rows found: " + cont);

             } else if(input.equals("help")){

                System.out.println("Avaliable commands: \n"
                        + " select * - Display the total of rows imported.\n"
                        + " select distinct - Displays the total of distinct rows based on a entered header.\n"
                        + " select [header] [value] - Display the header and all his rows based in the value entered."
                        + " quit - Quit the application. \n");

             }else{
                 System.out.println("Invalid command!");
             }
        }
    }  

    public static String getParameter(String pattern, String input){
        String header = "";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        while(m.find()) {
            header = m.group(1);
        }

        return header;
    }

    public static String getValue(String pattern, String input){
        String value = "";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        while(m.find()) {
            value = m.group(2);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit out your code out of your question. This is going against the rule of this site.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: You were told before not to edit code out of the question, so I'm locking it for now to prevent further edits.  You may discuss this further on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Answer (score 3):

#### `try`-with-resources

> ```
>         try {
>             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readerConfig.getPath()));
>
>             String row = "";
>             while ((row = br.readLine()) != null) {
>                 String[] properties = row.split(readerConfig.getDelimiter());
>                 rows.add(properties);
>             }
>
>             br.close();
>
>         } catch (IOException ex) {
>             ex.printStackTrace();
>         }
> ```

This is exactly the situation for which [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) was designed:

```
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readerConfig.getPath()))) {
            String row = "";
            while ((row = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] properties = row.split(readerConfig.getDelimiter());
                rows.add(properties);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If you have to compile against an old version of Java, the old way of doing this was to use a `finally` block.

```
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close;
            }
```

But that means that we have to define `br` before the `try` block.  It's easier to just do the `try`-with-resources.

#### `equalsIgnoreCase`

> ```
>              if(input.toLowerCase().equals("quit")){
> ```

Java has a method for this situation.

```
             if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
```

Perhaps that just does the same thing.  Or maybe Java has a more efficient way to check.  Note that if the strings are not equal, it doesn't have to lower case the whole string.  Only the part that it checks.

#### Typo

At least twice you write "Avaliable" when you presumably meant "Available".